# Render a nested object from API - Type Error: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I'm trying to access information from this API. I can access the first level however when I try to access any property past the first level I get an error stating `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'usd')`.

I am using a functional component and the useEffect() hook to call my API in React.

JSON API example:

```
{
  "name" : "Bitcoin",

  "market_cap" : {
    "usd" : 100
  }
}
```

From what I understand this is because the API has not been completely fetched so the first level is coming back as undefined. I am able to access the first level (`coin.name`), but when I try (`coin.market_cap.usd`) I get the error.

Any suggestions?

```
const Coin = () => {

    const params = useParams()
    const [coin, setCoin] = useState({})


    const url = `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${params.coinId}`

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(url).then((res) => {
            setCoin(res.data)
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })

    }, [])


    return (

       <div>
            <h1>{coin.name}</h1>
            <p>{coin.market_cap.usd}</p>   ------>> Error here
            </div>
       </div>  
    )
}

export default Coin
```

Comment: `({}).market_cap` is `undefined`... Your default value is not very useful to you.

Comment: For a safe check, try: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default value of your `coin` is empty object and since fetching data is `async` action when component tries to render for the first time it doesn't know about `market_cap` value so you need to add check for that prop when rendering.

This would solve your problem:

```
return (
        <div>
          {coin.name ? <h1>coin.name</h1> : null}
        {
          coin.market_data?.market_cap
          ? <p>{coin.market_data.market_cap.usd}</p>
          :  null
        }
        </div>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using coin properties before they have data from your api, as the initial value is an empty object {}

you should validate if the data exists or it will raise the error:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async() ={   ​
       ​await axios.get(url).then((res) => {
           ​setCoin(res.data)
       ​}).catch((err) => {
           ​console.log(err)
   ​    })
    }
    
    getData()
```

}, [])

```
...
```

return (

```
   <div>
        <h1>**{coin.name ? coin.name : ''}**</h1>
        <p>**{coin.market_cap ? coin.market_cap.usd : ''}**</p>   ------>> Error here
        </div>
   </div>  
)
```

Comment: Thank you Hector when I check if the data exists or if it is undefined then that does take away the error however, it still won't display the data.  Is there a way to fix this so I can still grab the data?

Comment: I edit my response, so you can refactor your useEffect function, since Axios returns a promise, you should execute with awai, but useEffect cannot be directly defined as an async function, so you have to define an async function inside useEffect and call it inmediatly. hope this helps